# popping keyboard in android

Tags: android, view, textfield, android-custom-view

I have created an app in which I used views and now i want the keyboard to popup when the view is touched i.e username,address or phone view I used the following lines of codes but it doesn't work

```
1)getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

this doesn't work and i tried the following too but no help

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
            .showSoftInput(username, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

please help me out with this.[This is the image of my custom view app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc0he.png)

My EditText XML is here

```
<com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField    
       android:layout_below="@+id/view" 
       app:mtf_image="@drawable/phon" android:id="@+id/view3"> 
<EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="40dp" 
          android:id="@+id/phoneNo"
          android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
          android:textSize="18sp"
          android:inputType="phone" 
          android:background="@drawable/phone"
          android:hint="Phone Number" />
</com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField>
```

Comment: Are you using EditText in your layout :

Comment: Yes i am using edit text.

Comment: is username your editText ?

Comment: copy your username XML here .

Comment: I can not copy xml here because it is too long

Comment: Yes My username is edit text

Comment: How can i add long xml here?

Comment: just add only EditText code of XML

Comment: <com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField  android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        app:mtf_image="@drawable/phon"
        android:id="@+id/view3">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/phoneNo"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:background="@drawable/phone"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
</com.github.florent37.materialtextfield.MaterialTextField>

Comment: i've added it it looks kinda mess here

Comment: and where you open keyboard ? copy that code also

Comment: Actually it just worked with a line of code i just tried right now and it works like a charm now thanks Himani

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(mMessage.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Where mMessage is your edittext.

Comment: Also, I used to use EditText.requestFocus() when opening keyboard. If it doesn't work, try it too.

Comment: non of these methods are working i don't know why and i am doing it in genymotion emulator but the keyboard isn't showing up

Comment: Can you just try once in physical device also?

Comment: Actually i don't have physical device these that's why